# Correct syntax for importing sass files within the asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have application.scss which looks exactly like this

```
[code]
/*
*/
@import "compass";
@import "compass/blah/blah";
@import "welcome";
[/code]
```

The welcome file uses compass mixins and the asset_path helper via erb <%= blah %>. So I thought the correct way to name the file itself was

```
"welcome.css.sass.erb"
```

and I include it in application.scss with

@import "welcome";

but that just forces rails to break with "Something went wrong" and no clues provided in the dev logs.

If I change the welcome filename to

welcome.css.erb

but make no changes to the @import declaration all is fine.

Can anyone explain why this is happening? Shouldnt the correct way be the former given use of scss, compass and asset_path?

Is there something wrong with the application.scss syntax?

With the later extension, im getting problems precompiling for production and I believe this problem is at the center of it all.

Comment: Where did you put the `"welcome.css.sass.erb"`? On an `@import` declaration?

Comment: go through this [sass import rules](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import) it will help you with your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [`compass-rails`](https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails/) and [`sass-rails`](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/) gems:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails' # if running rails 3.1 or greater
  gem 'compass-rails'
end
```

And you can use the provided [asset helpers](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/#features) directly in Sass without ERB:

```
.container
  background: url(image_path("background.png")) 0 0 no-repeat
```